# Getting Error- Invalid mail Attachment

Tags: asp.net, email

I am trying to send email with excel file attachment. But getting invalid mail attachment error.

Please help me.

Here is my code-

[image]

Comment: First save the Excel in a temp Folder in server. Then Map it in mail attachment.

Comment: I have saved excel in my hard disk. My computer download folder.

Comment: Create A folder in Your Project, save the file in that folder, then map it.

Comment: how can I do this ? Where to change  my code.

Comment: Wait i will give u solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code for Email sending-

```
 protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
    msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
    msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        String FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        MailAttachment mailAttachment = new MailAttachment(FileName, MailEncoding.Base64);
        // msg.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
        msg.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
    }

using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFrom.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";


       client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project name in solution explorer . Click on Add then Choose new folder name it MailDocuments. Use this code to Save it  and Attach It.

```
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            string Path = Server.MapPath("~/MailDocuments/");
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path + fileName);

            MailAttachment ma = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath("~/MailDocuments/" + fileName), MailEncoding.Base64);
            msg.Attachment.Add(ma);
        }

private bool SendEmail(string myIPAddress)
{
     bool emailsent = true;
     if (myemailaddress != "" && mypassword != "")
     {
         System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
         mail.To.Add(myemailaddress);
         mail.CC.Add("whoever@yahoo.com");
         mail.From = new MailAddress("do.not.reply@whatever.com",  "do.not.reply@whatever.com", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
         mail.Subject = "Type Subject Here";
         mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
         mail.Body = "Your IP address has changed to " + myIPAddress;
         mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
         mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
         mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
         client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourGmailEmail@gmail.com", "thepasswordforthataccount");
         client.Port = 587; // Gmail works on this port
         client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
         client.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail works on Server Secured Layer 
         try
         {
             client.Send(mail);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             emailsent = false;
         }
     }
   else
   {
      emailsent = false;
   }
   return emailsent;
}
```

Comment: above code u have written in btnSend Click Change in that.

Comment: I have change it.. but file is not saving in this folder and when i click browse on fileupload button it chooses file from my hard disk.

Comment: Invalid mail attachment '~/MailDocuments/ExpenseReport (2).xls'.

Comment: Error--The transport failed to connect to the server.

Comment: Its your server problem check its configured properly and firewall is open.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is myemailAddress and mypassword in this code---- Is it txtbox name ?                                          if (myemailaddress != "" && mypassword != "")

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51414/discussion-between-azhar-shahid-and-raghubar)